# Redirect stdin to stdout

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, redirection

I've got a script, ex myscript.sh, and it has to redirect to stdout what it gets from stdin (like a cat).

For example:

```
myscript.sh < myfile.txt > myfile2.txt
```

How to do this?

Also, how can i redirect the stdout in another file rather then myfile2.txt?

### My tries:

I tried using:

```
echo $*
```

And it only works using:

```
myscript.sh | cat myfile.txt
```

If i use:

```
myscript.sh < myfile.txt
```

it prints out nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot understand what you want: $* outputs the *positional* parameters and you did not supply any, so you got no output (apart from new-line).

`cat` does not read standard input when it is given a file to list, so `myscript.sh | cat myfile.txt` has the same effect as `myscript.sh ; cat myfile.txt` (not strictly true, but correct in terms of input/output).

If you want your script to copy input to output, then it should contain simply `cat`.

If you want output from $*, then you need to run `myscript.sh {parameters}`.

And what do you mean by "redirect the stdout in another file rather then myfile2.txt"? You presumably don't mean `... > myfile3.txt`.

Answer (score 4):

Try add `cat <&0` to your script where you want to carry out the redirection job.

The `&0` above represents the `stdin` file descriptor, and you're essentially putting things you get from `stdin` to `cat`.

Alternatively, use the following loop to do it yourself:

```
while read line
do
  echo "$line"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want to *duplicate* script input to terminal output, not redirect.

```
cat myfile.txt | tee /dev/tty | myscript.sh > myfile2.txt
```

or even simpler

```
cat myfile.txt; myscript.sh < myfile.txt > myfile2.txt
```